# [SKIP] No rule to make target None

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem that appeared overnight. All of my code is on an SVN and used to compile fine. This morning, I started getting this problem when compiling some packages:

```
[SKIP] No rule to make target None
```

I did not use the computer for about ten days because I was at a conference, but it was off so no updates were applied since the last time that I used it.

So here is what I tried.

```
roscreate-pkg foo
rosmake foo
```

And I got the same problem:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['foo']                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/robot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120918-154406                                                 
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['foo'] to:
['foo']                                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> foo [ make ]                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< foo [SKIP] No rule to make target None                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 0 failures.                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] /home/robot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120918-154406
```

I then applied all Ubuntu updates for 12.04, including all updates for ROS Fuerte. I created package foo2 and I still have the same problem. In my own packages, it seems like the build starts, but does not finish, because the ROS messages are not generated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44045/%5Bskip%5D-no-rule-to-make-target-none/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-18**:
Are the packages in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-09-18**:
Yes, everything is in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. roscd and rospack find work perfectly. By creating a new package foo, I wanted to ensure that it was not a dependency problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end, I uninstalled ROS with

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*
sudo apt-get autoremove ros-fuerte-*
```

Then, I rebooted, re-installed ROS, and everything is fine again.

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) on 2013-01-14**:
Same thing happened to me with a fresh install of groovy. It turned out some nasty stuff actually happened to my environment variables ( file ".bashrc" being damaged). You can check the variable ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is correctly set by running "export" in a terminal. It displays all variables defined.